# How do I undo a bzr ignore?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I mistakenly did

```
bzr ignore
```

For some files that I don't want to ignore. How do I undo the ignore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your **.bzrignore** file in repository. If you simply delete the entry for the files you ignored they should then be recognized by bzr again.